# How to get selected cell value on DataGrid SelectedCellsChanged in wpf?

Tags: asp.net, wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I want to get cell value on DataGrid selected cell Changed event in my wpf application.
Please anybody help me out of this.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selectedcellschanged.aspx ??

Answer (score 0):

you can use CurrentCellChanged or SelectedCellsChanged events

Comment: exactly.but how to get this on that particular event?

Comment: if you choose SelectedCellsChanged  try using e.AddedCells[i].Item

Comment: there is a great sample here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selectedcellschanged.aspx